# Adding "?" with rewritecond query string

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

I've a simple youtube video streaming - grabber site
& trying to make a mod rewrite but I'm having this problem,

current link: ***www.site.com/video.php?id=A6XUVjK9W4o***

trying to : ***www.site.com/watch?v=A6XUVjK9W4o***
(just like youtube)

my current htaccess code is,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^watch/?$ video.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it's not working.